# Transform to Observable only if not already Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, refactoring

I have a check which needs to combine 2 checks:

1. The first check is an observable to tell if the user is logged
2. The second check is a function which can return a boolean or an Observable

Is there a more elegant way of wrapping a value in an observable only if not observable already?
Or is there a way to combine the first check with the second when the second is Observable?
Or still refactor all this in a more efficent way?

Of course this code is an example to simulate what I get in the real app (see comments in code).

```
const getRandomBool: () => boolean = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;
const getRandomCheck: () => boolean | Observable<boolean> = () => {
  return getRandomBool() ? getAsyncCheck() : getSyncCheck();
};


const myFunction = (): Observable<boolean> | boolean => {

  // First check telling if user is logged, which the UserService returns as Observable<boolean>
  return of(getRandomBool())
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((isLogged) => {
        // This is the check which can be either boolean or Observable<boolean>
        const myCheck = getRandomCheck();
        
        return isLogged
            ? ​i​if(() => typeof myCheck === 'boolean', of(myCheck), myCheck)
            : of(!1)
     ​})
   ​)
};
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking first if "myCheck" was Observable and use `forkJoin`?

```
const myFunction: () => Observable<boolean> = () => {
  let myCheck = getRandomCheck();
  myCheck = isObservable(myCheck) ? myCheck : of(myCheck);

  return forkJoin([of(getRandomBool()), myCheck])
  .pipe(
    map(([logged, yourCheck]) => {

      return logged ? yourCheck : !1;
    })
  )
}
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by BizzyBob, in case myCheck is async and has a huge span it could pointlessly affect the whole execution.
So we can use `switchMap` to avoid the issue

```
const myFunction: () => Observable<boolean> = () => {
  let myCheck = getRandomCheck();
  myCheck = isObservable(myCheck) ? myCheck : of(myCheck);

  return of(getRandomBool())
  .pipe(
    switchMap((logged: boolean) => {

      return logged ? myCheck : of(!1);
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: This looks very nice!

Comment: The only downside I see here is that `myCheck` will always get executed, even when `isLogged = false`.  So if `myCheck` does any async work it could introduce a performance hit.

Comment: @BizzyBob actually I think the difference is minimal, since using other ways, such as `exhaustMap` or `switchMap` would require converting `isLogged` to another observable when it's false...
So I think that performance-wise there's no difference!

Comment: I agree with Sampgun. I think this is also the cleanest way of writing what I needed! Thanks to everyone for your time and support!

Comment: @BizzyBob now I get what you mean. You're saying that if myCheck has long execution that's waisted time when isLogged is false. I think you're right...we can adjust this using `switchMap` then...

Answer (score 2):

[There is isObservable method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/isObservable.ts)

**Example**

```js
const { of, iif, pipe, isObservable , operators: { mergeMap } } = rxjs;

const getAsyncCheck = () => of(Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)));
const getSyncCheck = () => Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
const getRandomBool = () => Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
const getRandomCheck = () => {
  return getRandomBool() ? getAsyncCheck() : getSyncCheck();
};


const myFunction = () => {


  return of(getRandomBool())
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((isLogged) => {

        const myCheck = getRandomCheck();
        const result = isLogged ? iif(() => isObservable(myCheck), myCheck, of(myCheck)) : of(false);
        return result;
     })
   ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
};

myFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of the `isObservable` method. Cool. So basically it's good this way, just have to change the check using `isObservable`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd coerce `randomCheck` to observable, then use `exhaustMap` to handle returning the proper observable; either `of(false)` when, `isLogged = false` or `randomCheck$` otherwise:

```js
const myFunction = (): Observable<boolean> => {
  const randomCheck$ = isObservable(randomCheck) ? randomCheck : of(randomCheck);

  return getIsLogged().pipe(
    exhaustMap(isLogged => isLogged ? randomCheck$ : of(false)),
    // take(1)
  );
};
```

If `getIsLogged()` doesn't complete, I think you need to use `take(1)` for angular guard.

Comment: the fact is that "isLogged" is actually returned as Observable that's why it's wrapped with `of` in my example!

Comment: Returning always observable wouldn't be an issue, since I'm actually implementing the `canActivate` in Angular, which accepts either `boolean` or `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: I didn't realize `isLogged` was observable, I thought use of `of` was part of your solution in `myFunction` :-)

Comment: ehehe don't worry. Checked the new solution and definitely looks good!

Comment: good hint about the `take(1)` (or better `first()`) because the isLogged$ is actually a BehaviourSubject, so yes, it doesn't complete :)